# Validation of A Byte Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a function in java that parses an array of bytes to determine if it follows a certain pattern. This pattern is as follows:

1. The first two bytes in an array are 1 and 0
2. The two bytes are followed by a random sequence of bytes terminated by a 0.
3. This random sequence of bytes is followed by another random sequence of bytes also terminated by a 0.
4. There are no bytes following this terminating 0.

I am having trouble thinking of the logic of how to approach implementing such a function.

Comment: whats the specific problem? You have the rules to match pattern.

Comment: How do you approach this? Directly. The rules are very clear, you just need to translate it into a program. Think about what's blocking you and make the question more specific please.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an initial array of bytes that's already initialized and has a length greater than 2:

```
byte[] array = ...
```

If the first two bytes are 1 and 0 respectively, then:

```
array[0] == 1 && array[1] == 0
```

You then say that there are two random sequences of bytes that follow that both **must** end with 0.  This means that we only have to specifically look for two 0s within the array after the first two indices.

```
Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 2, array.length)), 0) == 2
```

You must also check that the last byte is a 0:

```
array[array.length - 1] == 0
```

Comment: If I read OP correctly, there must be a 1, a zero, and two sequences of (non-zero) bytes each ending with a zero, and nothing more.  So you also need to check that `array[array.length-1] == 0` to meet all the conditions, if indeed they be such as I am understanding them.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Good catch!

Comment: The call to collections.frequency always returns a value of 0 for any input array of bytes of the desired format. How might I fix this?

Comment: Try passing `(byte) 0` as a parameter instead of just `0` and let me know if that fixes it